# SUMIFS - Sum all the cells with 'gelato' in the text but not ones called 'gelato_lime'

Tags: excel, sumifs

I want to use `SUMIFS` to sum everything in `Column A` if `Column C` equals `gelato`. It could be `gelato_blue`, `gelato_lemon`, `gelato_chocolate` - but I DON'T want it to sum any `gelato_lime`.

```
=SUMIFS(A:A, C:C, \*gelato*, C:C, "<>gelato_lime")
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

Why not one minus the other?

```
=SUMIFS(A:A, C:C, "gelato*") - SUMIFS(A:A, C:C, "gelato_lime")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your formula needs some syntax correction as below

```
=SUMIFS(A:A, C:C, "*gelato*", C:C, "<>gelato_lime")
```

[image: Sample data and result]

Comment: I actually entered the formula correctly the way you had it, but for some reason was pointing it to the wrong data - so it was working correctly. Thanks!!